# Crear autorizacion basada en roles MVC .NET6

Tags: c#, mvc, .net-6.0

Estoy intentando crear un mecanismo de autorización basada en roles en MVC con .NET6. he estado buscando en internet sobre como crear este sistema pero me encuentro con muchas dificultades ya que parece ser que todo esta haciendo referencia a Identity y confundo bastante este tema porque no se si esto significa que esos sitios que he visto para intentar enteder esto estan basados en Entity Framework Core ya que mi aplicación no esta haciendo uso de este mismo.
Os pongo en situación a ver si me podríais echar un cable

En el apartado de usuario obtengo el Id de Rol al que pertenece dicho usuario y todo eso lo guardo en sesión.

```
public IActionResult Login(UsuarioModel usuarioRequest) 
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(usuarioRequest);
    }
    UsuarioModel usuarioResponse = new();
    usuarioResponse = usuarios.ObtainUser(usuarioRequest);
    if (usuarioResponse == null)
    {
        return View(usuarioRequest);
    }
    if (HttpContext.Session.GetObject<UsuarioModel>("object") == null)
    {
        HttpContext.Session.SetObject("object", usuarioResponse);
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Dashboard", usuarioResponse);
}
```

Cuando hago `RedirectToAction` a Dashboard se me ha ocurrido filtrar los permisos de acceso mediante los datos cargados en sesion. Pero no se si esto es una alternativa 100% segura

```
public IActionResult Dashboard(UsuarioModel usuarioResponse)
        {
            if (HttpContext.Session.GetObject<UsuarioModel>("object") == null)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            return View(usuarioResponse);
        }
```

en program.cs tengo configurada la sesion de esta forma.

```
builder.Services.AddSession(options =>  
{
    options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
    options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
    
});
```

Con los datos en sesion entiendo que puedo jugar una vez cree la autorización con los ids de rol para poder dar permisos. Pero también he visto que es necesario crear la autenticación y me estoy haciendo bastante lio la verdad.

Espero podáis ayudarme

Comment: Hola alexandermarco, te invito a hacer el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primer medalla!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo primero, el `Identity` que seguramente has leido es otro, no se refiere a `Entity Framework`

El proceso de Login, consiste en 2 pasos

- Autentificación
- Autorización

A modo general, el primero tiene que ver con el `usuario` y `contraseña`; y el segundo con el `Rol`.

Después hay que entender que la tecnología Web en default no guarda estado, por lo que a cada página que entres debes logearte nuevamente, lo que obviamente no quiere nadie. Para guardar el login generalmente se usan cookies

**1.- Configurar**

En el program.cs agregas:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddCookie(options => {
                    options.ReturnUrlParameter = "returnUrl";
                    options.LoginPath = "/Login"; //Login es el nombre del controlador
                });


//...más configuraciones

var app = builder.Build();

//...más configuraciones

app.UseAuthentication();

//...más configuraciones
app.UseAuthorization(); //colocar justo arriba de los Map{Algo}
app.MapRazorPages();
app.MapControllers();
```

**2.- Login**

```
public Task<IActionResult> Login(UsuarioModel usuarioRequest) 
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(usuarioRequest);
    }
    UsuarioModel usuarioResponse = new();
    usuarioResponse = usuarios.ObtainUser(usuarioRequest);
    if (usuarioResponse == null)
    {
        return View(usuarioRequest);
    }

   var claims = new List<Claim>
   {
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "aqui_el_nombre_de_usuario"),
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "aqui_el_rol")
   };
   var userIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "login");
   ClaimsPrincipal principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(userIdentity);
   await HttpContext.SignInAsync(principal);
    return RedirectToAction("Dashboard", usuarioResponse);
}
```

**3.- Logout**

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Logout()
{
    await HttpContext.SignOutAsync();
    return Index();
}
```

**4.- Autorización**

Ahora para autorizar un controller y/o un action, colocas el atributo  `[Authorize]` arriba de él

Ejemplo

```
//[Authorize(Roles = "Administrador,Guardia,Secreteria")] //puedes colocar varios separados por coma
[Authorize(Roles = "Administrador")]
public class EquiposController : Controller
{
  //...
}
```

Comment: Entiendo el siguiente código que en **program.cs** esta instrucción **options.LoginPath = "/Login";** hace referencia al controlador y la acción que retornará verdad? al indicar **[Authorize]** me redirecciona a la pagina de login, sin embargo hay ciertas cosas que no entiendo del controlador. **var userIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "login");** tiene que llamarse login? y cuando hago la redireccion a **Dashboard** le indico  **[Authorize(Roles = "1")]** ya que el claim Role tiene el numero 1 pero cuando inicio sesion me redirecciona de nuevo a login cuando el claim rol es 1

Comment: 1) Claro, en el caso del ejemplo es "/login/index", siendo "login" el controlador e index el action, pero en mi caso index es default , entonces no era necesario colocarlo, quedando solamente "/login".  2) Eso es el tipo de autenticación, están los default (ver lista aqui: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.claims.authenticationtypes?view=netframework-4.8.1), al colocar cualquier otro valor que NO es default pasa a ser "custom", que quiere decir que nosotros crearemos el login, entonces la respuesta es que puede ser cualquier nombre.

Comment: La última pregunta no te la puedo responder, tendría que ver el código. Pero en esta linea `new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "1")` es donde deberías agregar que es rol "1".  Para corroborar el asunto, puedes quitar el `[Authorize]` (a modo de prueba) y dentro del "action" colocar `HttpContext.User.IsInRole("1")  lo que retornará si el usuario en cuestión está o no en ese rol`

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por compartir parte de tu conocimiento en ayudarme @yussef esta funcionando todo y sobretodo conseguir entender cada linea de código que hace paso a paso. Muchas gracias.

Comment: @alexandermarco cuanto me alegro que te funcionara finalmente. Saludos!